# compare two columns using Awk

Tags: awk

i need to compare different columns in a file and create a new column that store
 smallest value of all these columns
e.g test.txt

```
label col1  col2

A 0.999966  0.618701
```

output

```
label col1  col2 smallest 
A 0.999966  0.618701 0.618701
```

i tried

```
awk '{if($3 < $2) print}' test.txt > a

awk '{if($2 < $3) print}' test.txt > b

cat a b > c
```

can anybody suggest anything in awk

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    NR == 1 { print $0, "smallest"; next }
    {
        min = $1
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($i < min) {
                min = $i
            }
        }
        print $0, min
    }
' test.txt
```

Comment: thank you so much can you please add a little explanation, i understand first you printed smallest in header and then you give a loop for two columns telling print the value that is smallest but  i dont understand "min = $1" what is $1 here

Comment: Right, thats exactly what it is.